# JSlider error, but no clue where it's coming from

Tags: java, jslider

At some point in my program, the following error is being generated. Any idea what this is?

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI.calculateThumbLocation(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI.calculateGeometry(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI$Handler.componentResized(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I have an idea: show us your code so that we can know what causes this error

Comment: lots of people here are only excelent Java/C/Assembles coders, but no one is mindreader, no battery included

Comment: You need a longer stack trace, these are all java classes. You will need to now which of YOUR classes that this occurred in.

Comment: well, that is the stack trace that printed. and @Eng.Fouad, sorry to say, but do you see a class anywhere in that stack trace? didn't think so. that's why I have no code to post...lol. I don't see any of my classes listed there...

Comment: The problem is the way you customized your slider class. Since you refuse to post your SSCCE we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar intermittent NPEs pop up during initialization when setting a slider to use a custom ui that extended BasicSliderUI.  I fixed them by wrapping it in an invokeLater:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override public void run() {
            slider.setUI(new CustomSliderUI(slider));
        }
    });
```